# Белый экран смерти без www в WordPress на домене .рф

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, редирект, mod-rewrite

Есть сайт птица-музыка.рф. Если заходить по URL *птица-музыка.рф*, то все норм. А если добавить в URL *www.птица-музыка.рф*, то белый экран смерти.

В чем может быть проблема? В домене .рф, настройке редиректа?

Адрес WordPress и сайта в настройках *http://xn----7sbb1acpmu1ao3a9d.xn--p1ai*

htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index1\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index1.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сконфигурируйте .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Где www.site.ru - адрес вашего сайта

В итоге получится

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index1\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Либо, если есть проблемы с доменами на кириллице, используйте универсальный подход.                             
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^www].*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Просто добавить эти три строчки после # END WordPress, заменив www.site.ru на адрес сайта?

Comment: Удалить верхний кусок до # BEGIN WordPress, потом добавить RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^www].*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301] добавить до </IfModule>

Comment: Переправил еще раз, попробуй.

Comment: Удали все содержимое файла и скинь туда этот код.

Comment: В интернете полно материала. Выбирай какой хочешь, называется Переадресация 301 или 301 редирект

Comment: Я имел ввиду по настройке htaccess, чтобы понимать суть всех этих символов. В интернете полно материала и лажи среди него тоже полно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Выкинуть из htaccess-а первый блок. (а то и всё).
2. Прописать ОДИНАКОВЫЙ домен в обеих полях в настройках.
   2.1. Недодомены писать в [пуникоде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)!!!
3. Дать ВП самому сгненерировать правила в htaccess-е и больше в нём ничего не трогать (в блоке ВП все ручные изменения потеряются).

Больше НИЧЕГО ненужно.
Профит.